# How to compare an instance of an object inside an ArrayList to user input via Scanner

Tags: java, arraylist, input, collections

I'm trying to learn arraylist usage by myself, and i encounter a dilemma:

I have 3 classes, one father abstract class that has 2 childs, which instances of those classes are stored in an arraylist on the main program, my goal is to basically to "raise" the salary of an instance of employee (deliveryman or commercial), by retrieving user input from console and comparing that input with the corresponding attribute of ALL instances that my arraylist have, for example:

I want to raise by $300 or give a plus to an instance of deliveryman

user inputs name  "george" > (i need to search the instance which has by name george in it) and use the isPlus and setPlus methods on that instance. (all classes have  corresponding getters and setters for all attributes, and tostrings).

I don't know how to do it or implement because I'm new on arraylist usage so no background of what ive already tried

> Class Employee

```
public abstract class Employee {
   private static final int PLUS = 300;
   private static final int EMPLOYEEQTY = 3;

   protected String name;
   protected int age;
   protected double salary;

   public Employee(String name, int age, double salary) {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
      this.salary = salary;
   }
}
```

> Class Commercial

```
public class Commercial extends Employee{

   private double comission;

   public Commercial(String name, int age, double salary, double comission) {
      super(name, age, salary);
      this.comission = comission;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isPlus() {
      if (this.comission > 200 && this.age > 30) {
         return true;
      }else {
         return false;
      }
   }

   @Override
   public double setPlus() {
      if (isPlus() == true) {
         return this.salary+getPlus();
      }
      return salary;
   }
}
```

> Class DeliveryMan

```
public class DeliveryMan extends Employee{
   private String zone;

   public DeliveryMan(String name, int age, double salary, String zone) {
      super(name, age, salary);
      this.zone = zone;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isPlus() {
      if (this.zone.equalsIgnoreCase("zona 3") && this.age > 25) {
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public double setPlus() {
      if (isPlus() ==  true) {
         return salary+getPlus();
      }
      return salary;
   }
}
```

> Class Program

```
public class Program {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      String name,zone,opt;
      Integer age;
      Double salary,comission;
      ArrayList<Employee> al = new ArrayList<>();
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

      for (int i = 0; i < Employee.getEmployeeqty(); i++) {

         System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del empleado:  ");
         name = sc.next();
         System.out.println("Ingrese la edad del empleado: ");
         age = sc.nextInt();
         System.out.println("Ingrese el salario del empleado: ");
         salary = sc.nextDouble();
         System.out.println("Es el empleado un Repartidor o un Comercial?");
         opt = sc.nextLine();

         switch (opt.toLowerCase()) {
            case "repartidor":
            System.out.println("Ingrese la zona del repartidor: (ej: zona 3)");
            zone = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            al.add(new DeliveryMan(name, age, salary, zone));
            break;
            case "comercial":
            System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de la comision del comercial: ");
            comission = sc.nextDouble();
            al.add(new Commercial(name, age, salary, comission));
            break;
            default: System.out.println("Opcion ingresada no es valida, por favor, indique si es un repartidor o un comercial.");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Think of arraylist as an array which dynamic size.

Comment: Employee name isn't static, which  is static is the qty of employees in order to give a limit of iterations to the for inside main and PLUS which is basically a raise and is always an static and final value

Comment: Don’t use `condition == true`. Just use `condition`. Likewise, don’t use `if(condition) return true; [else] return false;` Just use `return condition;`

Comment: Can i get clarification for the "Likewise, don’t use if(condition) return true; [else] return false; Just use return condition;" because that's kinda new to me and i don't understand the logic behind it

Comment: `zone.equalsIgnoreCase("zona 3") && age > 25` is a condition, which evaluates to a `boolean` result. You can use `boolean` value in `if` statements or loop conditions, but you can also store them in variables or return them like any other type. `if(condition) actionA; else actionB;` means “if condition evaluates to `true`, do action A else do action B”. So `if(condition) return true; else return false;` means “if condition evaluates to `true`, return `true` else (if it evaluates to `false`) return `false`”. Which is redundant; `return zone.equalsIgnoreCase("zona 3") && age > 25;` does the same

Comment: @Holger thanks a lot for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over arraylist.

Fetch the object from arraylist by comparing name with the help of equals method.

Update object.
Insert updated object in arraylist

```
ArrayList<Employee> al = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0 ; i < al.size() ; i++){
    if((al.get(i).name).equals(user_input_name)){
          al.salary(i) =  al.salary+increment_salary;
    }

}
```

Comment: When you remove an element from the list you’re iterating over, you must decrement the index, as otherwise, you’ll miss the next element. Further, since you are adding the matching element at the end of the list, you’ll will encounter it again, leading to an infinite loop. Only the other bug of missing one element after a match prevents this here. But as soon as there are at least two matching elements, you will encounter the infinite loop. But removing and adding the element is entirely obsolete anyway, `for(Employee a: al) if(a.name.equals(user_input_name)) a.salary +=  increment_salary;`…

Comment: You inserted several errors. Either, you use a for-each loop, `for(Employee a: al)`, or you have to use `al.get(i)` correctly.